# Bind instance of function to an element

Tags: javascript

The code below works fine when there is only one div on the page. With multiple divs, and the function called multiple times, they interfere with eachother, as shown in [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6m6spzey/5/).

My tought was, as long as the variables are not in the global scope, and I bind them to the element with `this`, there would be no problem. But obviously I was wrong :-)

How would I bind an instance of the function to each element without them interfering with eachother?

And secondly, will the instance of the function disappear if I remove the element from the page?

**HTML**

```
<div id="was_100" class="was">
    <div id="cx_100" class="cx"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="was_200" class="was">
    <div id="cx_200" class="cx"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function test(o) {
    var my = this;
    my.was = document.getElementById("was_" + o);
    my.cx = document.getElementById("cx_" + o);
    alert(my.was.id);

    my.move = function (e) {
    e=e||window.e;
    var el=e.target||e.srcElement;
       var left = e.clientX - el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        my.cx.style.left = left + "px";
    }

    my.was.addEventListener("mousemove", my.move, false);
}

test(100);
test(200);
```

Comment: The problem is that `this` will not be a freshly-allocated object, but the `window` object. If you call the function with `new` then `this` will refer to a new object in each function call.

Comment: Pointy is right. If you change `test(100)` to `var foo = new test(100)` and do the same for `test(200)` then the function will behave as a constructor, and the `this` keyword will be unique in each call.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy and @grammar, that works. But now I have two global scope variables that still will be around when I remove the element from the DOM. I could do `foo=""` after removing the `<div>`, but is there a way to remove them automaticly?

Comment: And the jquery related part is?

Comment: Well one thing you could do would be to start the function with `var my = {}`, or just call the function with `new` and simply throw away the result (like, `new test(100);` instead of saving the result in a variable).

Comment: @Pointy. Works perfect, thank you. I learn something new every day :-) Maybe you can create an answer, so I can close the question?